# Android Studio IDE

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello i have a problem in Android Studio to when i create a new project file in tree become less.

this images:
[From This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pzf9I.png)
[To This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mtu8q.png)

I didn't do anything because i didn't know to do what work!!

**What should I do to fix it?**

Please **HELP** Me

Comment: Looks normal to me. The left part is a tree view with expandable nodes. Have you tried to expand one of the node? If a node is expanded or collapsed you can see by the triangle on the left of each node.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and ه solved this problem, but after this some folders go